# Pandas map values between rows

Tags: pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'player': ['John', 'Will', 'John', 'Will'],
                   'round': [0, 0, 1, 1],
                   'points': [3.0, 5.0, 3.4, 6.5]})
```

---

I would like to create a new column 'next_points', where 'points' for each player is mapped to prior round, like so:

```
  player  round    points   next_points
0   John      0       3.0   3.4
1   Will      0       5.0   6.5
2   John      1       3.4   ...
3   Will      1       6.5   ...
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `groupby` with `shift`

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('player')['points'].shift(-1)
df
Out[33]: 
  player  round  points  new
0   John      0     3.0  3.4
1   Will      0     5.0  6.5
2   John      1     3.4  NaN
3   Will      1     6.5  NaN
```

Comment: thank you. given the fact that my working example is not my full dataframe, how do I assign this new column back to the full dataframe?

Comment: @8-BitBorges df['new'] = df.groupby('player')['points'].shift(-1) already assign ?

Comment: What if we have `df=pd.DataFrame({'player':['John', 'Will', 'John', 'Will', 'John', 'Will'],'round':[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2],'points':[3.0, 5.0, 3.4, 6.5, 13.4, 16.5]})`